# What does this 'shift' do here?

Tags: mouse

I'm trying to understand this value assignment:

```
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(2 ((shift) . 1)))
```

I know that `shift` is a bitwise shift. But I don't understand what is the result of this operation here (what is the value of `mouse-wheel-scroll-amount`). And for that matter, why did the coder decide to use this operation rather than giving a decimal value here.

Comment: `C-h v mouse-wheel-scroll-amount`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shift` in this case is a symbol, not a function. Note that the variable is given a quoted list, so nothing inside is evaluated.

From the documentation of this variable (which you can access via `describe-variable`), you can give different amounts of scrolling for different (keyboard) modifiers.

In this case, the normal scroll is 2 lines, or 1 if <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: @NVaughan I would add that the bitwise shift functions in elisp are `lsh` and `ash`, not `shift`.  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Bitwise-Operations.html#Bitwise-Operations